# Discord bot with python not working and giving error

Tags: python, macos, discord

I don't really know what to put for "What I tried" because I have no idea how this stuff works, I am new to this.

My code is

```
import discord

TOKEN = "token"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("{0.user} is now online!".format(client))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

and my error is

https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ecahevoqos.py

Comment: You got an SSL error, so your code probably isn't the problem. I'm not an SSL expert so I can't tell you what the exact problem is, but I'd start with updating discord.py and python.

Comment: Hey! I installed python 3.10 and ran the code with idle but its saying that I don't have the discord module installed so I decided to run it with terminal and its giving me this error https://paste.pythondiscord.com/uhohojutox

Comment: I tried again and now its not saying that I need to install discord but its giving me this error https://paste.pythondiscord.com/egaricuhus

Comment: I read it but It didnt help me too much and im on mac

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I was able to get it working